# Parsing complex json into dataframe using R

Tags: json, r

I am not able to parse the following complex json output from JIRA in to a dataframe using R. I am able to partially parse the data into dataframe using PowerShell. But wish to accomplish this in R. Can someone please suggest how to proceed? The solutions listed in this forum using Rjson or jsonlite or RJSONIO did not work with this example.

```
  [
        {
            "expand": [
                "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields"
            ],
            "id": [
                "22513"
            ],
            "self": [
                "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/22513"
            ],
            "key": [
                "DATA-1314"
            ],
            "fields": {
                "issuetype": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001"
                    ],
                    "id": [
                        "10001"
                    ],
                    "description": [
                        "A task that needs to be done."
                    ],
                    "iconUrl": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "Task"
                    ],
                    "subtask": [
                        false
                    ],
                    "avatarId": [
                        10318
                    ]
                },
                "timespent": {},
                "project": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/10300"
                    ],
                    "id": [
                        "10300"
                    ],
                    "key": [
                        "DATA"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "Data"
                    ],
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324"
                        ],
                        "24x24": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324"
                        ],
                        "16x16": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324"
                        ],
                        "32x32": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "fixVersions": [],
                "aggregatetimespent": {},
                "resolution": {},
                "customfield_10500": {},
                "customfield_10700": {},
                "resolutiondate": {},
                "workratio": [
                    -1
                ],
                "lastViewed": [
                    "2017-07-14T15:33:40.422-0700"
                ],
                "watches": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/DATA-1314/watchers"
                    ],
                    "watchCount": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "isWatching": [
                        true
                    ]
                },
                "created": [
                    "2017-07-12T11:56:12.000-0700"
                ],
                "customfield_10022": {},
                "customfield_10023": [
                    "1|i001zz:"
                ],
                "priority": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3"
                    ],
                    "iconUrl": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "Medium"
                    ],
                    "id": [
                        "3"
                    ]
                },
                "customfield_10300": {},
                "labels": [
                    [
                        "data"
                    ]
                ],
                "customfield_10017": {},
                "customfield_10018": {},
                "timeestimate": {},
                "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": {},
                "versions": [],
                "issuelinks": [],
                "assignee": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "key": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "accountId": [
                        "1234567890"
                    ],
                    "emailAddress": [
                        "UserName@somecompany.com"
                    ],
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "24x24": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "16x16": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "32x32": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ]
                    },
                    "displayName": [
                        "FName LName"
                    ],
                    "active": [
                        true
                    ],
                    "timeZone": [
                        "America/Los_Angeles"
                    ]
                },
                "updated": [
                    "2017-07-12T13:07:51.000-0700"
                ],
                "status": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/1"
                    ],
                    "description": [
                        "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it."
                    ],
                    "iconUrl": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/open.png"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "Open"
                    ],
                    "id": [
                        "1"
                    ],
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "self": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2"
                        ],
                        "id": [
                            2
                        ],
                        "key": [
                            "new"
                        ],
                        "colorName": [
                            "blue-gray"
                        ],
                        "name": [
                            "To Do"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "components": [],
                "timeoriginalestimate": {},
                "description": {},
                "customfield_10010": {},
                "customfield_10011": {},
                "customfield_10012": {},
                "customfield_10013": {},
                "customfield_10014": {},
                "customfield_10015": {},
                "customfield_10401": [
                    "FName"
                ],
                "customfield_10600": {},
                "customfield_10402": [
                    "TESTING DATA DOWNLOAD USING API"
                ],
                "customfield_10006": {},
                "customfield_10403": [
                    {
                        "self": [
                            "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10100"
                        ],
                        "value": [
                            "i_file"
                        ],
                        "id": [
                            "10100"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "customfield_10007": {},
                "customfield_10800": {},
                "customfield_10008": {},
                "aggregatetimeestimate": {},
                "customfield_10009": {},
                "summary": [
                    "testing"
                ],
                "creator": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "key": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "accountId": [
                        "1234567890"
                    ],
                    "emailAddress": [
                        "UserName@somecompany.com"
                    ],
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "24x24": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "16x16": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "32x32": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ]
                    },
                    "displayName": [
                        "FName LName"
                    ],
                    "active": [
                        true
                    ],
                    "timeZone": [
                        "America/Los_Angeles"
                    ]
                },
                "subtasks": [],
                "reporter": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
                    ],
                    "name": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "key": [
                        "UserName"
                    ],
                    "accountId": [
                        "1234567890"
                    ],
                    "emailAddress": [
                        "UserName@somecompany.com"
                    ],
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "24x24": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "16x16": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ],
                        "32x32": [
                            "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345678901215406a6830d189deda8cc%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                        ]
                    },
                    "displayName": [
                        "FName LName"
                    ],
                    "active": [
                        true
                    ],
                    "timeZone": [
                        "America/Los_Angeles"
                    ]
                },
                "aggregateprogress": {
                    "progress": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "total": [
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "customfield_10000": {},
                "customfield_10001": {},
                "customfield_10002": {},
                "customfield_10004": [
                    "{}"
                ],
                "customfield_10400": [
                    "DA-000000"
                ],
                "environment": {},
                "duedate": [
                    "2017-07-13"
                ],
                "progress": {
                    "progress": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "total": [
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "votes": {
                    "self": [
                        "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/DATA-1314/votes"
                    ],
                    "votes": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "hasVoted": [
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Check out the package `jsonlite`?

Comment: This doesn't look very rectangular. What exactly do you want the final table to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is something i often have to do as well. for me, i usually save the json as a list in R, then create a dataframe from there based on what i want the dataframe to look like. here is some code to illustrate:

```
library(tidyverse)
jira <- fromJSON(.....) #this is whatever code you used to get the data from JIRA in R
df <- data_frame(id = jira$id, fielddescription=jira$fields$description)
```

basically you use the elements within the `jira` object you created to build your own dataframe. sometimes you'll need to use multiple `$` to access nested items, as illustrated above by `jira$fields$description`

you may also want to explore the `tidyjson` package. it was meant for problems like this. i found it to be simpler to construct my own dataframe as illustrated here, but for certain use cases or programming styles that may be preferable, depending your taste and situation.

Comment: Very useful answer.

Comment: Can you pl help me with how to authenticate JIRA access when using fromJSON?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all of that in a set of `''` and assign it to a variable `json`.  Then,

```
library(jsonlite)
l <- fromJSON(json, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
str(l)
```

As others commented, this won't parse down easily to a data.frame, but here it is as a list.

```
List of 1
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ expand: chr "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields"
  ..$ id    : chr "22513"
  ..$ self  : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/22513"
  ..$ key   : chr "DATA-1314"
  ..$ fields:List of 60
  .. ..$ issuetype                    :List of 7
  .. .. ..$ self       : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10001"
  .. .. ..$ id         : chr "10001"
  .. .. ..$ description: chr "A task that needs to be done."
  .. .. ..$ iconUrl    : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "Task"
  .. .. ..$ subtask    : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ avatarId   : int 10318
  .. ..$ timespent                    : Named list()
  .. ..$ project                      :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ self      : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/10300"
  .. .. ..$ id        : chr "10300"
  .. .. ..$ key       : chr "DATA"
  .. .. ..$ name      : chr "Data"
  .. .. ..$ avatarUrls:List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ 48x48: chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324"
  .. .. .. ..$ 24x24: chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324"
  .. .. .. ..$ 16x16: chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324"
  .. .. .. ..$ 32x32: chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"
  .. ..$ fixVersions                  : list()
  .. ..$ aggregatetimespent           : Named list()
  .. ..$ resolution                   : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10500            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10700            : Named list()
  .. ..$ resolutiondate               : Named list()
  .. ..$ workratio                    : int -1
  .. ..$ lastViewed                   : chr "2017-07-14T15:33:40.422-0700"
  .. ..$ watches                      :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ self      : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/DATA-1314/watchers"
  .. .. ..$ watchCount: int 1
  .. .. ..$ isWatching: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ created                      : chr "2017-07-12T11:56:12.000-0700"
  .. ..$ customfield_10022            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10023            : chr "1|i001zz:"
  .. ..$ priority                     :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ self   : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3"
  .. .. ..$ iconUrl: chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg"
  .. .. ..$ name   : chr "Medium"
  .. .. ..$ id     : chr "3"
  .. ..$ customfield_10300            : Named list()
  .. ..$ labels                       : chr [1, 1] "data"
  .. ..$ customfield_10017            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10018            : Named list()
  .. ..$ timeestimate                 : Named list()
  .. ..$ aggregatetimeoriginalestimate: Named list()
  .. ..$ versions                     : list()
  .. ..$ issuelinks                   : list()
  .. ..$ assignee                     :List of 9
  .. .. ..$ self        : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
  .. .. ..$ name        : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ key         : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ accountId   : chr "1234567890"
  .. .. ..$ emailAddress: chr "UserName@somecompany.com"
  .. .. ..$ avatarUrls  :List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ 48x48: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 24x24: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 16x16: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 32x32: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. ..$ displayName : chr "FName LName"
  .. .. ..$ active      : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ timeZone    : chr "America/Los_Angeles"
  .. ..$ updated                      : chr "2017-07-12T13:07:51.000-0700"
  .. ..$ status                       :List of 6
  .. .. ..$ self          : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/1"
  .. .. ..$ description   : chr "The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it."
  .. .. ..$ iconUrl       : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/open.png"
  .. .. ..$ name          : chr "Open"
  .. .. ..$ id            : chr "1"
  .. .. ..$ statusCategory:List of 5
  .. .. .. ..$ self     : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2"
  .. .. .. ..$ id       : int 2
  .. .. .. ..$ key      : chr "new"
  .. .. .. ..$ colorName: chr "blue-gray"
  .. .. .. ..$ name     : chr "To Do"
  .. ..$ components                   : list()
  .. ..$ timeoriginalestimate         : Named list()
  .. ..$ description                  : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10010            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10011            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10012            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10013            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10014            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10015            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10401            : chr "FName"
  .. ..$ customfield_10600            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10402            : chr "TESTING DATA DOWNLOAD USING API"
  .. ..$ customfield_10006            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10403            :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ self : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10100"
  .. .. .. ..$ value: chr "i_file"
  .. .. .. ..$ id   : chr "10100"
  .. ..$ customfield_10007            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10800            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10008            : Named list()
  .. ..$ aggregatetimeestimate        : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10009            : Named list()
  .. ..$ summary                      : chr "testing"
  .. ..$ creator                      :List of 9
  .. .. ..$ self        : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
  .. .. ..$ name        : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ key         : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ accountId   : chr "1234567890"
  .. .. ..$ emailAddress: chr "UserName@somecompany.com"
  .. .. ..$ avatarUrls  :List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ 48x48: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 24x24: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 16x16: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 32x32: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. ..$ displayName : chr "FName LName"
  .. .. ..$ active      : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ timeZone    : chr "America/Los_Angeles"
  .. ..$ subtasks                     : list()
  .. ..$ reporter                     :List of 9
  .. .. ..$ self        : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=UserName"
  .. .. ..$ name        : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ key         : chr "UserName"
  .. .. ..$ accountId   : chr "1234567890"
  .. .. ..$ emailAddress: chr "UserName@somecompany.com"
  .. .. ..$ avatarUrls  :List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ 48x48: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 24x24: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 16x16: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. ..$ 32x32: chr "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/12345678901206a6830d189deda8cc?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%1234567890121"| __truncated__
  .. .. ..$ displayName : chr "FName LName"
  .. .. ..$ active      : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ timeZone    : chr "America/Los_Angeles"
  .. ..$ aggregateprogress            :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ progress: int 0
  .. .. ..$ total   : int 0
  .. ..$ customfield_10000            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10001            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10002            : Named list()
  .. ..$ customfield_10004            : chr "{}"
  .. ..$ customfield_10400            : chr "DA-000000"
  .. ..$ environment                  : Named list()
  .. ..$ duedate                      : chr "2017-07-13"
  .. ..$ progress                     :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ progress: int 0
  .. .. ..$ total   : int 0
  .. ..$ votes                        :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ self    : chr "https://somecompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/DATA-1314/votes"
  .. .. ..$ votes   : int 0
  .. .. ..$ hasVoted: logi FALSE
```

Comment: The list is what I was getting processing the json output. I couldn't proceed beyond this.